# Shopify Control ELSE IF?

Tags: shopify

I am trying to write a simple else if statement in a .liquid theme.

Here is my code.

```
  {% if page.template_suffix == 'survey' %}
  {% include 'header_fullbg' %} 
  {% elsif page.template_suffix == 'surveystart' %}
  {% include 'header_fullbg2' %} 
  {% else %}
  {% include header-layout %} 
  {% endif %}
```

Here is a screen shot to see the "intelliSense"
[image]

As you can see the else if statement isn't being recognized as being correct? Can someone please help me? I have confirmed this isn't working.

Comment: I'm not familiar with liquid, but shouldn't `header-layout` be in quotes? Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: I am not too familiar either. I don't think so, the reason being is that that code was there before I started even messing with the theme code. I don't understand how that piece works. The include looks inside of a folder called 'snippets' but there isn't a file in there called 'header-layout'. So I believe that is set somewhere else (though I know not where). It does work for other pages though - I have confirmed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it figured out. The syntax is correct.

I forgot I had another piece of code adding the footer snippet which was messed up.

I fixed it! Thanks for looking.

BEFORE

```
  {% if page.template_suffix == 'survey' %}
  {% include 'footer_fullbg' %} 
  {%elsif page.template_suffix == 'surveystart' %}
  {%else %}
  {% include footer-layout %}
  {% endif %}
```

AFTER

```
  {% if page.template_suffix == 'survey' %}
  {% include 'footer_fullbg' %} 
  {%elsif page.template_suffix == 'surveystart' %}
  {% include 'footer_fullbg' %} 
  {%else %}
  {% include footer-layout %}
  {% endif %}
```